# How to set current image in container with chocolat jquery?

Tags: jquery, chocolat.js

I am using this jquery plugin chocolat: https://chocolat.gitbook.io/chocolat/options

I almost got it to work how I want it. The only thing which I can't get to set is by default make the light box have the first image already opened in the container.

My code is to be found here: [www.bitchel.nl/test.html](http://www.bitchel.nl/test.html)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/chocolat.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/chocolat.css" type="text/css" media="screen" >

<body>
<div id="example3">
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="series/1.jpg" title="caption image 1">
        <img width="100" src="series/mini/1.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="series/2.jpg" title="caption image 2">
        <img width="100" src="series/mini/2.jpg" />
    </a>
    <a class="chocolat-image" href="series/3.jpg" title="caption image 3">
        <img width="100" src="series/mini/3.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="container2" style="width: 100%; max-width:1000px; height: 100%; max-height: 1000px; background: #E0E0E0;"></div>
</body>

 <script>

            Chocolat(document.querySelectorAll('#example3 .chocolat-image'), {
                container: document.querySelector('#container2'),
                imageSize: 'contain',
        loop: true,
        allowZoom: false,
            })
</script>
```

I think I have to do something with a function current or default image. But I can't seem to find the right option. Could somebody have a look for me. I think it's probably easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

After instantiating Chocolat you can get access to its api using :

```
const { api } = Chocolat(document.querySelectorAll('#example3 .chocolat-image'), {
            container: document.querySelector('#container2'),
            imageSize: 'contain',
            firstImageIndex: 0,
            loop: true,
            allowZoom: false
        });
```

Then simply call `open()` api method to open the first image:

```
        // Opens the first image
        api.open();
```

Comment: @Mitchel Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.